# Consuming Rest webservices using REST client mozzilla

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, rest-client

I am able successfully execute GET Request to the service, now I want to know how to execute POST, PUT,DELETE command

through Rest client i executed OPTION command and i got this result

```
<application>
<doc jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 1.17 01/17/2013 04:27 PM"/>
<grammars>
<include href= "http://localhost:8081/de.vogella.jersey.todo/rest/application.wadl/xsd0.xsd" >
<doc title="Generated" xml:lang="en"/>
</include>
</grammars>
<resources base="http://localhost:8081/de.vogella.jersey.todo/rest/">
<resource path="todos">
<method id="getTodosBrowser" name="GET">
<response>
<ns2:representation element="todo" mediaType="text/xml"/>
</response>
</method>
<method id="getTodos" name="GET">
<response>
<ns2:representation element="todo" mediaType="application/xml"/>
<ns2:representation element="todo" mediaType="application/json"/>
</response>
</method>
<method id="newTodo" name="POST">
<request>
<representation mediaType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<param name="id" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
<param name="summary" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
<param name="description" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
</representation>
</request>
</method>
<resource path="count">
<method id="getCount" name="GET">
<response>
<representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
</response>
</method>
</resource>
<resource path="{todo}">
<param name="todo" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
<method id="getTodo" name="GET">
<response>
<ns2:representation element="todo" mediaType="application/xml"/>
<ns2:representation element="todo" mediaType="application/json"/>
</response>
</method>
<method id="getTodoHTML" name="GET">
<response>
<ns2:representation element="todo" mediaType="text/xml"/>
</response>
</method>
<method id="putTodo" name="PUT">
<request>
<representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
</request>
<response>
<representation mediaType="*/*"/>
</response>
</method>
<method id="deleteTodo" name="DELETE"/>
</resource>
</resource>
</resources>
</application>
```

now can you please tell me how to execute PUT,POST,DELETE commant? what should i write in body and url ?

**THANKS A LOT**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're currently making requests, though you could give my plugin https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest a try. Post an issue on the Issues tab if you have any problems.